# System of four first-order partial differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Question**: Consider the wave equation: $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$$ for a smooth function $u(t,x)$

Letting $v=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $w=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, write down a system of four first-order partial differential equations for $u,v$ and $w$ which is equivalent to the wave equation

**My answer**: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)=v(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=w(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,t)=f(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=f(x,t)$$

Would this be sufficient? Do I need to add any clarification at the bottom about $f(x,t)$? Is there anything extra that I should add when answering these types of questions?

This seems like a standard question, if possible could someone link me to a standard model result?

**New answer**: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)=v(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=w(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,t)=\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t\partial x}$$

**Correct answer**: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t)=v(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)=w(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,t)=\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}(x,t)$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(x,t)=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}(x,t)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the last two equations, write just one equation to express the PDE, and another one to express the equality of mixed derivatives, $\partial^2 u/\partial x \partial t = \partial^2 u/\partial t \partial x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ive added a new answer, is this ok? Should write the 3rd one in terms of $u$ instead of $w$ and $t$. Sorry for being pedantic, but it would mean a lot if you could verify this for me.

Comment: Not quite right yet, since the fourth one is not a first-order equation!

Comment: Oh yea thanks, but how is it possible to express the equality of mixed derivatives as a first order pde?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)$ can be written in terms of $v$.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}(x,t)=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}(x,t)$$ Is that right? (Thanks for being so patient with me)

Comment: There you have it!